# React HandleClick in the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux

Read React tutorial and docs, can't find any information about action that going in child component `<a onClick="{function(){ this.props.handleClick...` but declared in parent compnonent.

When we should do it? Why not just do all stuff in child component? We have Redux, Flux but people do it every day, why?

(example with parent component)

```
var SongList = React.createClass({
  logTrack: function(track) {
    console.log(track)
  }

  render: function () {
    var trackNodes = this.props.data.map(function(track, i) {
      return (
        <Song
          key={i} 
          handleClick={(val) => this.logTrack(val)} // pass function through props
         >
          {track}
        </Song>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="row">
        {trackNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
})

var Song = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <a onClick={ function () { this.props.handleClick('some value') }>
      {this.props.children}
    </a>
  }
})
```

Comment: `handleClick={(val) => this.logTrack(val)}`

Answer (score 0):

There's no concrete action here, it comes down to separate of concerns and what make sense in your app.  Often times the child / dumb components won't know what to do with something that's clicked. That's a job better suited in the parent. For example if you have a list of items (parent) the list items (children) often just want to notify the parent that they were tapped. The parent is the one that manages the state of the list, so the parent might want to mark an additional item as selected (multi select) or it might want to unselect the previous selection and mark the new one as selected (single select). It's not reasonable to have child components know about all their peers to make this happen.

Comment: Redux and Flux created for SAY parent compnonent that child was clicked, right or not?